# Can't connect to database while testing

Tags: symfony, doctrine

If I make request through POSTMAN, record is created in my main database `api`.
I want to execute tests in database called `api_test`. When I run the test

> Testing  [critical] Error thrown while running command
> "doctrine:database:drop --connection=test --force=1 --if-exists=1".
> Message: "An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]
> php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not
> known"

This is absolute nonsense for me. My test url is same like my production one with only database name changed

```
.env
    DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:toma123@database:3306/api?serverVersion=5.7&charset=utf8mb4"
    DATABASE_TEST_URL="mysql://root:toma123@database:3306/api_test?serverVersion=5.7&charset=utf8mb4"
```

In my doctrine.yaml I have

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App

when@test:
    doctrine:
        dbal:
            connections:
                   test:
                        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_TEST_URL)%'

when@prod:
    doctrine:
        orm:
            auto_generate_proxy_classes: false
            query_cache_driver:
                type: pool
                pool: doctrine.system_cache_pool
            result_cache_driver:
                type: pool
                pool: doctrine.result_cache_pool

    framework:
        cache:
            pools:
                doctrine.result_cache_pool:
                    adapter: cache.app
                doctrine.system_cache_pool:
                    adapter: cache.system
```

AGAIN! Can create a record through postman with my `default` connection.

Comment: @msg Didn't understand what `d:d:d` means.

Comment: Shorthand for `doctrine:database:drop`. Still runnable, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `when@test` section only takes effect when the environment matches the condition: `test` in this case.

Since you are not passing the `-e` argument, it's executing in the default environment, so the `test` connection doesn't exist.

Even if the environment matches, the connection [is used by the orm mapping](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#shortened-configuration-syntax) and the command you are using stills uses the default mapping (and connection).

Just rely on [standard environment configuration](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#configuration-based-on-environment-variables): remove the `when@test` section, rename `DATABASE_TEST_URL` to `DATABASE_URL` and put it in the `.env.test` and execute the command `bin/console d:d:d -e test --force`.